# How to use apache to reroute files to other directory?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am maintaining a website someone else wrote. He used absolute path in the html to request assets files, and he assumed the project is always installed at the root of the domain.

Now I am testing the website; I installed the project at a subdirectory. And I want to redirect files that start with a certain characters to a subfolder.

For example, he wrote something like this

```
<img src="/en/wp-content/themes/.....">
```

So now the server will start searching files at the root like `example.com/en/wp-content/....`

I installed the project at `/foo/en`, `example.com/foo/en`. I want to use .htaccess to reroute urls that start with `/en/wp-content/themes` to `/foo/en/wp-content/themes`. What should I do?

This is how I wrote it:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^en/wp-content/themes/(.*)$ /foo/en/wp-content/themes/$1
```

But it doesn't work....

Comment: Is mod-rewrite enabled and are you allow to use htaccess overrider?

Comment: Yes, when I screwed something, the website stopped working (not able to access).

Comment: Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu). They are the only content in my .htaccess

Comment: Only /foo/en has .htaccess

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156048/discussion-between-webdesigner-and-joshua-leung).

Answer (score 0):

I would change the line only a little bit just to be sure that this is not interfering with any other htaccess files use [L] or [END]:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?en/wp-content/themes/(.*)$ /foo/en/wp-content/themes/$1 [L]
```

[L] means Last https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l

[END] https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_end

Comment: I am wondering, if the url is example.com/en/..., will the .htaccess in the root takes over? or foo/en? If I want to rewrite url like this, should I create .htaccess in the root or /foo/en?